# How to remove "%E2%80%8B/" unwanted symbols while fetching URLs from Excel running through eclipse , actually while getting URL from Excel data

Tags: java, eclipse, rest-assured

Actually when I am able to pass the datas in Excel which are all URLs, when printing `"/api​/policy​/aboutsaccospolicy​/create"` it is printing correctly but when passing it in URL `"/api/api%E2%80%8B/policy%E2%80%8B/aboutsaccospolicy%E2%80%8B/create"`

The code is:

```java
res = given().spec(requestSpecification(message1)).log().all();
response = res.when().get(api).then().log().all().extract().response();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what those characters are, but I'd start by using an URL decoder.

Comment: `%E2%80%8B` is URL UTF-8 encoding for U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE - a very strange thing to have in a URL

Comment: how to parse those while passing

Comment: The string `"/api​/policy​/aboutsaccospolicy​/create"` mentioned in your question also contains zero-width spaces, even if they are not visible (since they are spaces with a width of 0 pixels). Does your code contain somewhere zero-width spaces (`>​<`)? Please also show your definition of your variable `api`.

Comment: Special characters like that must be encoded that way when they are used in a URL. You can convert them back using `java.net.URLDecoder.decode(string, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`